# Calcular raices enesimas de Integer en Haskell

Tags: haskell

Necesito una función que realice lo siguiente

```
raizEnesima :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer

raizEnesima 8 3 == 2
raizEnesima 7 8 == 1
raizEnesima 4 2 == 2
```

He intentando realizar la función, de la siguiente forma, pero me da error, y no sé el motivo:

```
raizEnesima :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
raizEnesima n x = (round . fromInteger) (n**(1/x))
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El operador `(/)` es de los *"Fraccionales"* (`Fractional`), mientras que `(**)` es de los *"Racionales"* (`Rational`). Ambas *clases de tipo* no tiene instancias para `Integer`.

Explicado mejor: no existen los tipos `Fractional Integer` ni `Rational Integer`, con lo que no puedes usar números *Enteros* en la expresión `n**(1/n)` sin más.

En otros lenguajes existen conversiones de tipo automáticas. Pero haskell, las operaciones entre números son *"internas"* o, dicho de otro modo, una operación de dos enteros da siempre como resultado otro entero. Las operaciones `(/)` y `(**)` aplicadas a enteros producirían resultados erróneos, razón por la cuál no se definen para estos números. Es necesario convertirlos a otro tipo más adecuado.

Lo más simple es dejar al compilador que elija el tipo más adecuado a partir del número entero, para lo que está la función `fromIntegral`:

```
raizEnesima :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
raizEnesima n x = round $ (fromIntegral n**(1/fromIntegral x))
```

Puedes usar `fromInteger` en lugar de `fromIntegral` si quieres, aunque así queda más general.